# Number of spanning trees in a wheel graph without an external edge.

Tags: graph-theory, generating-functions

[image]

How many different spanning tree contains n-element graph shown above?
Determine the generating function for considered sequence.
I am asking for advice.

Comment: I don't know how to start.

Comment: Start by actually finding all the spanning trees for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3,..$ and see if you can find a pattern after a few of them.

Comment: @user180834: The simplest and most obvious place to start is by calculating the number of spanning trees for the first few values of $n$, say $n=1,2,3,4,5$, to see if some pattern or natural recursion appears. This should be an almost automatic response when you don’t see anything better to try.

Comment: @user180834 do you understand my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a tree of that form with final vertex $n+1$, there are two cases. Case $1$ is when vertex $(n+1)$ is connected to vertex $0$. In this case we classify all the trees according to how many vertices are in the same external block as vertex $n+1$ (an external block is a path between consecutive external vertices. Notice that if we delete all of the vertices in an external block we'll get a tree with $n+1-k$ external vertices where $k$ is the number of vertices in the block.

Hence the number of trees of this type is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}f_{n+1-k}$

Now count the vertices in which vertex $n+1$ is not connected to vertex zero. Then after removing that vertex we get a tree in which the maximum vertex is $n$. There are $f_n$ of this type.

Then the recursion is $f_{n+1}=f_n+\sum\limits_{i=0}^nf_i$

You also have $f_{0}=1,f_{1}=1,f_{2}=3$

From here you can follow: $f_{3}=8,f_{4}=21,f_{5}=55$

Comment: Thanks. Now I am trying to determine generating function. 
Let be $d(x)$ generating function for sequence $f_n$.
I get: $d(x) = \frac{1-x}{1-3x+x^2}$ and get stuck. Help :)

Comment: @user180834: I think that your numerator is slightly off: I get $d(x)=\frac{1-2x}{1-3x+x^2}$. Use the quadratic formula and a bit of algebra to factor the denominator as $(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)$, then decompose into partial fractions to get $$d(x)=\frac{A}{1-\alpha x}+\frac{B}{1-\beta x}\;.$$ Then use the fact that $$\frac1{1-\alpha x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\alpha^nx^n\;,$$ combine into a single summation, and read off $f_n$.